# Expired passport with expired visa cannot be found

Tags: visas

My husband misplaced his expired passport with his visa...we want to travel and he has a new passport but no visa to show what do we do...our visa is expired..he has none to show.help

Comment: More information will be required, including your husband's citizenship and to where you want to travel, and the nature of the visa.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're concerned about an expired passport with an expired visa in it. Neither of these things are useful. You need an *unexpired* passport and an *unexpired* visa.

Comment: You don't say which country, but if you wanted to argue that they gave you a visa before, so they should give you a visa again, then most countries will be keeping track and know that you had a visa.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the passport number for inclusion in a new/current visa application?

Comment: @brhans But to be clear, you can, depending on the country, use an [expired passport containing an unexpired visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118672/what-happens-to-visas-that-last-longer-than-a-passport), along with an unexpired passport, i.e. two separate books.

Comment: @user71659 - yes this is true, but irrelevant. The OP specifically writes "no visa to show" & "our visa is expired" - so there is apparently no *unexpired* visa in play here.

Comment: @brhans I agree, the question required me to read it a few times to understand. The pieces of information are a bit scattered.

Comment: @brhans perhaps they want (or have been told) to submit the old passport and visa as evidence to support the application for a new visa.

Comment: @phoog yes perhaps that is the case - but it's not expressed in the question. The OP should clarify what they think the problem is.

Comment: @brhans I agree.  I would vote to reopen the question if it were edited to explain why the expired visa or expired passport is thought to be needed.  As it is, I would leave the question closed.

Answer (score 2):

Although you don't say which country you are from, or where you want to travel to, the procedures are pretty much the same whatever the answer.

1. Apply for a new passport
2. When you receive it apply for a new visa.
3. When you receive the new visa use it to travel.

If by some chance you are in a country without a valid visa for it, then still apply for a new passport through your country's embassy, and then leave back to your home country and apply for a new visa there.